# Let $|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant (x-y)^2$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$ Show that $f$ is a constant.

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Let $|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant (x-y)^2$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$ Show that $f$ is a constant.

This seemed quite straightforward just using the definition of the derivative, but I've ran into some weird issue. I have that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant (x-y)(x+y) \Longrightarrow \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{x-y} \leqslant x+y$$

from where I have that $\lim_{x\to y} x+y = 2y$.

If the problem assignment would instead had $|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant |(x-y)^2|$ I would have gotten $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant |x-y||x+y| \Longrightarrow \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{x-y} \leqslant |x-y|$$

from where $\lim_{x\to y} |x-y| = 0$. And $f$ would be a constant. What might I be missing here?

Comment: Is it $(x-y)^2=\lvert x-y\rvert\lvert x-y\rvert$ or is it $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$?

Comment: As the comment above by @Gae.S. says, you seem to be using $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$, while the statement is about $(x-y)^2 = (x-y)\cdot(x-y)$.

Comment: Thanks. Bad mistake.

Comment: Notice the question doesn't say $f$ is differentiable, or continuous, or anything but a real function. It's still true that only constant functions satisfy the condition.

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: @MatthewPilling we don't need to. The condition implies differentiability (as the limit exists, and is equal to 0).

Comment: @Clement C. Ah yes, very true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, you have: $|f(x+h) - f(x)| \le ((x+h) - x)^2=h^2=|h|^2\implies \left|\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right|\le |h|\implies \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \left|\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right| = 0 \implies \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 0\implies f'(x) = 0\implies f = \text{constant}.$

Comment: Nice proof (+1).

Comment: @Angelo: Thanks. I like to use the "h" in the proof. It seems like most books does that too.

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leqslant (x-y)^2
$$
so
$$
\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leqslant |x-y|
$$
so
$$
\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \to_{y \to x} 0.
$$
Thus $f'=0$ and $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 3):

We needn't assume $f$ is differentiable, or even continuous. Just use the triangle inequality:$$|f(y+h)-f(y)|\le\sum_{k=1}^n|f(y+hk/n)-f(y+h(k-1)/n)|\le n(h/n)^2=h^2/n$$for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so $f(y+h)-f(y)=0$.

Comment: +1 for not using limits _explicitly_.